# JSON API - submit textarea with JSON no Javascript from HTML - is this possible?

Tags: html, json, forms

Imagine the following:

> myapi.com/json/create/

Is awaiting JSON and returns some result.

HTML:

```
<form action="myapi.com/json/create/" method="post">
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The user inputs the JSON into the textarea and the API shall accept it.

User input in the textarea:

```
{
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

The API is expecting that the `POST` body is the JSON itself. Can I achieve this with an HTML form or not (Ajax required)?

Comment: So what's the problem here? You can parse the string out of the text area, convert it toJson and then send it to the server using javascript. The question is not properly asked though.

Comment: The User inputs the JSON. The question is if I can send a pure JSON post body by using an HTML form only.

Comment: Well... if your API is specting a string instead of a JSON formatted value and parse it server-side, then you can. Otherwise you'll need javascript and probably ajax to do it client side, which seems the correct solution for me.

Comment: No you cannot. The HTML standard defines that form data is send in a specific format. Also the example is not JSON. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-0

Comment: I had a look at this: https://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/ however it requires me to split the input I want to put the whole JSON at once.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong JSON example btw i replaced it with a valid one.